# Using the " | " character

Tags: browser, character, autohotkey

I use a spanish layout keyboard which has some symbols such as `| @ #` use the combination `altgr + number`. In many cases this is find but I have found certain cases were this doesnt work. I normally get around it by copy pasting the symbol, but it doesnt allow copy paste either. Most recently I have been using auto hot keys to use other combos to faster input certain characters.

However I am working with code academy now and I cant find a way of using `|`. I have tried different scripts such as

```
:*:bar::|

#f::
Send |
return

^w::
Send |
return

!o::
Send |
return
```

The first will be detected, but instead of being substituted for | bar dissapears and no character is seen. Ive tried the others inside my navigator (Chrome) for example in the search bar and they work, but have no effect in the codecadamy input.

Any way I can get aroung it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this instead:

```
#f::
Send, {Asc 124}
return
```

I use a spanish keyboard too. c:

Comment: It worked! thanks a lot, any idea why this might be so? I would like to increase my knowledge in the field of scripting and auto hot keys

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but i think that its because it can be used as an "OR" in the expressions read it here: https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm

Answer (score 0):

Update to the latest version of AutoHotkey_L and make sure you install the Unicode version. Your code is completely valid and all your 4 approaches would work.